# Moving or copying files between repositories in Github

Tags: github

Is it possible to copy/move a file or directory between two different Github repositories using the Github web interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the GitHub web interface, I don't think so.... however there are a couple of other options.

**Using Git Bash**

1. Clone Source Repo and Destination Repo to local (`$ git clone http://github.com/arepo`)
2. Using Explorer, Bash, whatever, copy/move the file(s) from the
   source to the destination (`$ mv repoa/filea.txt repob/filea.txt`)
3. Git Commit (`$ git commit`), Git Push (`$ git push`)

**Using Git Extensions**

1. Open Git Extensions
2. Open your Repo
3. Click File Tree in the bottom tabs.
4. Find your file(s) you want to move/copy, right-click it and hit "Save As"
5. Save to your other Repos' location
6. Switch over to that Repo in Git Extensions
7. Commands > Git Push